# Why do we need to declare the variable before we use it in some languages, but not in others?

Tags: java, python

How is memory allocated for a variable declaration in Python vs. Java? Without a compilation step how does an interpreted language know how much memory is needed for a variable?

Comment: look up strong typing vs weak typing.

Comment: @rpg711 Variable declaration can be mandatory in weakly typed languages too. And even when you might see it as not mandatory like in JavaScript, declaring a variable can set its scope.

Comment: Might it have something to do with interpreted vs. compiled languages?

Comment: @dystroy but ultimately it's more or less just convention, because most/all of those languages have closures anyways

Comment: It's decoupled from interpreted vs. compiled as well as typing rules. There are no restrictions preventing someone from creating a compiled language with strong typing that doesn't require variable declarations. Purely a design decision on the part of the language creators.

Comment: @dystroy why, using a variable without declaring it sets the scope directly at where you first use it, same as declaring the variable, it makes no difference whether or declare it or just use it in a weakly typed language. you might end up with really confusing, hard to read code, but it is all the same functionally

Comment: @rpg711 In JavaScript a variable you use without declaring it is in the global scope, not "where you first use it" (which is a common source of bugs).

Comment: @dystroy well, in python I believe the variables are treated as local variables when values are assigned to them, this question is not about javascript (well, the tags aren't) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question?rq=1

Comment: It seems I asked a stupid question:-) But thx,I still figured something out from the comments.

Comment: @deathlee It's not a stupid question. It's a little broad though, and you weren't very clear. And the discussion derailed a bit :p It seems as if no one here has a definitive answer.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ i'll guess the only people that actually know are those that work on the interpreters themselves, most people don't need to concern themselves with the fine details of typing, we just accept strong typing and weak typing, there is no real benefit to going deeper and investigating how those variables are allocated because we're dealing with high-level languages where most of the time everything but type(and sometimes even type) are abstracted out of the syntax/language

Comment: @rpg711 Strong vs weak typing is not the answer to this question. Both Python and Java are considered strongly typed. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#Typing and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29. The difference between a strong vs weakly typed language is how hard it is to subvert the type system. For example, C is a weakly typed language because you can cast things to and from void * without the compiler knowing what you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before being usable, variables must be allocated a memory location and then initialized--whether in [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514553/how-to-declare-an-array-in-python), or even [Logo](http://www.terrapinlogo.com/Help/declare.html).

Declare means that *you* make that variable come to life with a specific snippet of code, with (using Java as an example) something like

```
int i;
Person p;
```

These are declared, but not initialized. They are now assigned a location in memory--which, in some languages, may be ever-changing, both in location and size. But regardless, there is now some physical location in memory that the runtime environment can query, to retrieve the variable (either an indirect pointer to it, or the actual location itself).

Now that it has an empty "box" in which to go, it must be filled, which is to say it must be "initialized":

```
i = 3;
p = new Person();
```

Now there is something concrete in the box. It is ready for use. Attempting to use it before its initialized will result (in Java) in a `NullPointerException`.

Some languages require you to declare variables, in order to explicitly allocate memory for it (location and/or size). Some languages do this memory-allocation for you. As stated in the comments to both your question and this answer, there's a lot of variation.

Comment: I think someone misread this as you saying Python must have its variables declared, when you really meant that python must have its variables initialized (or else how would you use them?)

Comment: Both of your definitions are wrong.

Comment: Okay, so two downvotes so far, with no criticism on what the problem is. This is a pretty basic concept. I'd like to know what language does not do this.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around (in e.g. C)? Declaring gives you memory, initializing puts stuff there. No downvote from me :p, but I'm [unsure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11008311/645270) if your first sentence is true. It might just be that people frown upon you calling it _declaring_.

Comment: @user2357112: Of course, I switched them around. Fixed.

Comment: this is right... the python interpreter must have some concept of the variables it's dealing with or it would have issues performing operations on the variables

Comment: Better, but that's still a highly nonstandard definition of "declare". Also, many languages don't assign variables to locations in memory. For example, in Python, it's fully possible for a global variable's dict entry to change location over the course of a program's execution.

Comment: @user2357112: I've updated it to incorporate your comment, but I don't think this level of accuracy is necessary to a newbie question such as this.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a newbie question. It arises amongst beginners, sure, but it's tough to answer :p

Comment: My primary concern here is the definition of "declare". You're using it to refer to an entirely separate concept from the standard usage. Variable declarations are things like `int x;` or `var x;` or `Dim x As Integer`. It doesn't have anything to do with allocating storage for the variable. For example, if you declare an automatic variable `int x;` in C, that doesn't assign storage for the variable. The variable is allocated storage on the stack every time the function is entered, at runtime, and that storage may be at a different location every time. If you declare a VLA `int x[n]`...

Comment: it may even be allocated a different amount of space each time.

Comment: @user2357112: Ah. I see. I'll change it from "declare" to "allocate a physical storage location".

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ: The question itself, about the concept of declare and initialize, is not a newbie question. [*This question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090669/why-do-we-need-to-declare-the-variable-before-we-use-it-in-some-languages-but-n) is. But you're right. I'm learning something myself here.