# Basic Variable Indexing

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you do a simple index/array in Python?
For example, in a traditional BASIC language, all you would have to do is something like

```
10 Dim V(5)
20 For N = 1 to 5:V(N)=2^N+1/N:? N,V(N):Next
```

which would output:

```
1  3.0
2  4.5
3  8.33333333333
4  16.25
5  32.2
```

If I wanted the weights of Gaussian quadrature, I could do:

```
UL=5
[x,w] = p_roots(UL)
for N in range(UL):
     print N,w[N]
```

which works:

```
1  0.236926885056
2  0.478628670499
3  0.568888888889
4  0.478628670499
5  0.236926885056
```

but if I try my BASIC, as it would seem to be

```
UL=5
for N in range(1,UL+1):
    V[N]=2**N+1.0/N
    print N,V[N]
```

which rejects it as

```
    V[N]=2**N+1.0/N
NameError: name 'V' is not defined
```

and if I try to mimic the Gaussian example

```
UL=5
[V]=2**UL+1.0/UL
for N in range(1,UL+1):
    print N,V[N]
```

I get

```
    [V]=2**UL+1.0/UL
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

In terms of arrays/indexing, isn't V[N] the same as w[N] (which works in its example)?
All of the Python documentation seems to jump into more complicated cases, without providing more rudimentary examples like the above.

Comment: You need to check the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial) for how to make arrays (`list`s) in Python.

Comment: When you want to make a list in Python, put the brackets around its contents, not the name of the variable...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare an array in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514553/how-to-declare-an-array-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Your errors seem clear: in your first you have not defined V at all (compare with your BASIC version where you used Dim V) and in your second you have assigned V to a single value (2**UL+1.0/UL), not a list of values.

However, you should note that Python lists are not arrays, and you do not size them. Instead, you compose them as you go by appending. For instance, in the first version:

```
UL = 5
V = []
for N in range(1,UL+1):
    V.append(2**N+1.0/N)
```