# Algorithm to find change in direction in raster

Tags: python, algorithm, raster

I have a raster containing 0 and 1 as a numpy array, all pixels with a 1 are connected forming a line. This line is 1 pixel thick at all places. Using a pathfinding algorithm I have a list of the coordinates of all points (column, row), including the start and end point. 
The shape of my line is a squared U/rectangle missing the top part.

I want to find the points where the direction of the line changes for a longer stretch. For example from going down to going to the right, or from going to the right to going up.

I have looked at [Finding the point of a slope change as a free parameter- Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45063260/finding-the-point-of-a-slope-change-as-a-free-parameter-python); however since I my points are all either connected horizontally, vertically or diagonally this does not work. Also my u-shape can be diagonally in the array, therefore I am looking for the point where the type of connectivity changes for more than 2 pixel. Below is an example of my data, I would like to find (5,3)/(6,4) and (6,7)/(5,8)

```py
a = np.array([[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],
              [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

list_of_points = [(0,2),(1,2),(2,3),(3,3),(4,3),(5,3),(6,4),(6,5),(6,6),(6,7),(5,8),(4,8),(3,7),(2,8),(1,8),(0,8)]
```

Comment: What do you want to do if the path gently curves?

Comment: @MattTimmermans that is a good question - keep it, I only want the point where abrupt changes occure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have 3 directions for the U shape: down, right and up. You can follow the line and the directions using the next rules where O is the current position, and X are possible next pixels:

1. Down

```
...
.0.
XXX
```

2. Right

```
..X
.0X
..X
```

3. Up

```
XXX
.0.
...
```

And  following the next algorithm (pseudocode)

```
while next move can be down:
    move down
// here ends down line

while next move can be right:
    move right
// here ends right line

while next move can be up:
    move up
// here ends up line
```

If the U shape can be diagonally like this:

```
.......
...1...
....1..
1....1.
.1.11..
..1....
```

you can define different matrices for what down, right and up mean.
i.e.

```
// down
...
.0X
.XX

// right
.XX
.0X
...

// up
XX.
X0.
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your approach and it works for my problem