# How to create an array of shapes in VPython?

Tags: arrays, vpython

I'm trying to create an array of spheres in VPython, each with a manually entered position. Something like:

```
ball[0] = sphere(pos=vector(-1,4,9))
ball[1] = sphere(pos=vector(-2,6,6))
ball[2] = sphere(pos=vector(0,6,1))
```

etc. The problem is that I keep getting an error reading "IndexError: list assignment index out of range". How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

see [How to declare an array in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514553/how-to-declare-an-array-in-python).

You also might want to consider using a [compound](https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/compound.html)

**Modified code:**

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56461496/how-to-create-an-array-of-shapes-in-vpython
from vpython import *
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514553/how-to-declare-an-array-in-python
ball=[]
ball.append(sphere(pos=vector(-1,4,9)))
ball.append(sphere(pos=vector(-2,6,6)))
ball.append(sphere(pos=vector(0,6,1)))
```

**Result:**

[image]