# How to vertically print 2d list with different lengths in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In fact this I try to do.

I have a class call card

```
class Card(object):
def __init__(self, value, folldown,canMove):
    self.value = value
    self.folldown = folldown
    self.canMove=canMove
```

And I use this to print

```
for i in range(len(cards)):
  for j in range(len(cards[i])):
       print cards[i][j].value
```

I want to print a 2d list with different sizes`a=[[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]`

an I want to print like this

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
  2 2
    3
```

I was trying to print like this

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  for j in range(len(a[i])):
       print a[i][j]
```

but the result was

```
0
1
0
1
2
0
1 
2 
3
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Can you show your code please with the errors you are getting so we can help troubleshoot this?

Comment: Play around with [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and see if you can get it to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2D arrays in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856948/2d-arrays-in-python)

Comment: Sorry if you feel that I need some one to write my code. I haven't to much experience on python, and my code is too difficult to understand so I though that put this example would be better  @MorganThrapp

Comment: The post you put is for 2D arrays with the same size @200OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
print '\n'.join(['\t'.join([str(x[i]) if len(x) > i else '' for x in a]) for i in range(len(max(a)))])

#0    0    0
#1    1    1
#     2    2
#          3
```

Comment: For my solution I use this an I add .value on the x `print '\n'.join(['\t'.join([str(x[i].value) if len(x) > i else '' for x in a]) for i in range(len(max(a)))])`

Answer (score 1):

Another, one line solution

```
a = [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
from itertools import izip_longest
print "\n".join(("\t".join(map(str,l)) for l in izip_longest(*a, fillvalue="")))
```

you get:

```
0   0   0
1   1   1
    2   2
        3
```