# 2D array (not list) in python

Tags: python, sorting

I want to make a 2D array (not list) from 2 given lists. How would I do that?
For example, I want to generate a 2D 2by5 array with the list [1,2,3,4,5] and [6,7,5,9,34]
And also how would I iterate that array.
I have tried this

```
#import the necessary module
import array as arr

list1 = [2,3,5,7,1]
list2 = [13,17,19,23,29]

myarr = arr.array('i')
index = 0
for i in list1:
    myarr[0][index] = i
    index = index+1
index = 0
for i in list2:
    myarr[1][index] = i
    index = index+1

print(myarr)
```

Got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 10, in <module>
    myarr[0][index] = i
IndexError: array index out of range
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2D arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856948/2d-arrays-in-python)

Comment: using numpy? ..

Comment: the `array` module does not support multidimensional arrays.

Comment: No unfortunately that does not

Comment: If you can't use `numpy`, then why *must* you use the `array` module?

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation of the array module:

> This module defines an object type which can compactly represent an array of basic
> values: characters, integers, floating point numbers. Arrays are sequence types and
> behave very much like lists, except that the type of objects stored in them is
> constrained.

So, and array is 1D, and you can't have an array of arrays like you can have list of lists.  2D arrays are not possible.  As others have said: Numpy will be your friend here.

Answer (score -1):

Take an empty array first and take inner `array` as `integer array`
And then append values as follows

```
#import the necessary module
import array as arr

list1 = [2,3,5,7,1]
list2 = [13,17,19,23,29]

myarr = []

myarr.insert(0, arr.array('i'))
for i in list1:
    myarr[0].append(i)

myarr.insert(1, arr.array('i'))
for i in list2:
    myarr[1].append(i)

print(myarr)
```